# Removing from pandas dataframe all rows having less than 3 characters

Tags: python, pandas

I have this dataframe

```
Word    Frequency
0   :       79
1   ,       60
2   look    26
3   e       26
4   a       25
... ... ...
95  trump    2
96  election 2
97  step     2
98  day      2
99  university  2
```

I would like to remove all words having less than 3 characters.
I tried as follows:

```
df['Word']=df['Word'].str.findall('\w{3,}').str.join(' ')
```

but it does not remove them from my datataset.
Can you please tell me how to remove them?
My expected output would be:

```
Word    Frequency

2   look    26

... ... ...
95  trump    2
96  election 2
97  step     2
98  day      2
99  university  2
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try with

```
df = df[df['Word'].str.len()>=3]
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of attempting a regular expression, you can use `.str.len()` to get the length of each string of your column. Then you can simply filter based on that length for `>= 3`

Should look like:

```
df.loc[df["Word"].str.len() >= 3]
```

Answer (score 1):

Please Try

```
 df[df.Word.str.len()>=3]
```